# How to do conditional statement of validation from controller name in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Example:

- account_controller: do not validate a password
- password_controller: validate a password

my idea is...

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
...
  validates :username,
    :presence => true
  validates :password,
    :presence => { :if => :passord? }
...
  def password?
    # self.controller.to_s == 'password'
  end
end
```

First of all, my idea is wrong?

Anyone have another good idea?

Comment: @taro this is a fine way of doing it. Why don't post it as an answer? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add virtual attribute to your model and conditional validation:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :skip_password_validation

  validates :password, :unless => :skip_password_validation

end
```

And put something like this into controller:

```
user.skip_password_validation = true
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Sorry for late reply.